# En java, ¿en qué bloque de memoria se almacenan los metodos static y constantes static?

Tags: java, manejo-de-memoria

Soy nuevo en esto, leí que cuando se ejecuta un programa Java, la JVM separa la memoria en dos principales bloques: stack y heap. Pero qué sucede en memoria cuando se utiliza un método static o una constante static ?

Agrego un par de videos que pueden ayudar a comprender mi pregunta:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PrNeKnIqjZE&t

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jzJjMefsFKE

Comment: Hay dos cosas distintas: la memoria utlizada para guardar la definición del método (=su bytecode) y la memoria usada para su ejecución (= espacio requerido por las variables locales y temporales). ¿A cuál de ellos te refieres?

Comment: Principalmente a la de ejecución, pero me ayudaría aún más sabiendo que pasa en su bytecode.

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.1

> Memory that can be shared between threads is called shared memory or heap memory.
>
> All instance fields, static fields, and array elements are stored in heap memory. In this chapter, we use the term variable to refer to both fields and array elements.
>
> Local variables (§14.4), formal method parameters (§8.4.1), and exception handler parameters (§14.20) are never shared between threads and are unaffected by the memory model.
>
> Two accesses to (reads of or writes to) the same variable are said to be conflicting if at least one of the accesses is a write.

Un atributo `static` está en el Heap. Tiene un objeto asociado a la propia clase que lo contiene, y dicho objeto es el que tiene definido el atributo.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.5

Un método `static` es como cualquier otro método; su invocación hace que se añada el método al *stack* y que se cree un *frame* que es el contiene la memoria necesaria para la ejecución (no sólo la memoria necesaria para las variables sino también la memoria necesaria para operandos intermedios).

No he visto del todo los vídeos que enlazas, pero un comentario de una cosa que creo que no aclaran suficientemente: un método sólo ocupa memoria en el *stack/frame* al ser invocado. En el momento de compilar se calcula la memoria necesaria para la ejecución del método y ese valor se guarda en el *.class*; cada vez que se invoca el método es cuando se hace reserva/uso de dicha memoria. Un método no invocado sólo ocupa la memoria necesaria para su *bytecode*, y eso no está ni en el *heap* ni en el *stack*.

Answer (score 0):

En JAVA a mí me enseñaron que adicionalmente a lo que conocemos como 2 bloques de memoria la stack y heap, realmente se derivan mas bloques de memoria:

1. Memoria de código.
2. Memoria auxiliar.
3. Memoria para el heap.
4. Memoria para la pila de ejecución.

Las variables y métodos declarados en una clase como static se almacenan en:

1. Memoria de código.

La Máquina Virtual de Java reparte la memoria en tres partes: En la que deposita el código compilado de las clases que va a usar; en la que va siguiendo la ejecución de main, para lo que usa una pila; y, por último, en la que va guardando los objetos que se van construyendo y que se llama heap (cuya traducción literal es montículo, pero es una estructura de datos particular en programación).